# Background Application in Windows IoT Core stops responding

Tags: remote-debugging, windows-10-iot-core, background-task, gatt

I created a Background Application for Windows IoT Core on a Raspberry Pi 3. It is to become a hub application for a "smart home remote" ([Nuimo](https://www.senic.com/en/)) which uses BLE GATT to communicate.

The odd thing is that after a short time of running, the application simply stops responding and also drags Visual Studio along. VS then responds very slowly, has trouble detaching from the debugging process, shows "waiting for a background task to complete" dialog. However, no exceptions seem to be thrown (I enabled breaking on all exceptions). This makes it very difficult to find the cause of the problem.

I tried:

- removing parts of the application
- enabling breaking on all exceptions
- combining multiple events coming from the BLE device to prevent flooding the application with events.

Unfortunately none of this helped.

Relevant documentation I read:

- https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/docs/backgroundapplications
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/bluetooth-dev-faq
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/gatt-client
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/access-sensors-and-devices-from-a-background-task

Therefore I'm wondering whether anybody could share experience and hints where to look for the issue.

The code is at https://github.com/wind-rider/nuimo-hub and https://github.com/wind-rider/nuimo-windows (too much to post here since I don't know what part the issue is in)

Update: in the process explorer (via Windows Device Portal) I see that suddenly the memory used by the app drops when it stops responding, but its process (backgroundTaskHost.exe) is not immediately gone. It seems that somehow the Background App is unloaded, and that Visual Studio doesn't notice it since the host process is not shut down?

Now - how to know why the task is unloaded?

- I assume that a Windows IoT Core background app is a special kind of background task that is not limited by the [resource constraints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/support-your-app-with-background-tasks#background-task-resource-constraints) applying to background tasks for "normal UWP apps"? Quote: "*Background Applications are applications that have no direct UI. Once deployed and configured, these applications launch at machine startup and run continuously without any process lifetime management resource use limitations.*" (from https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/docs/backgroundapplications)

Comment: Has this code line `_deferral.Complete();` executed?

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT No, I put a breakpoint and a Debug.WriteLine("") there but I never saw the breakpoint being hit.

I fiddled around with the bluetooth code (made it follow https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/gatt-clientbetter), did something with Session.MaintainConnection and some other things and delayed an expensive Philips Hue API call to later in the loading process and now somehow the code became more reliable, *but I have no idea what was the root cause which frustrates a lot*.

Comment: still some things are very much wanted:

- hints for debugging strategies when VS / Windows IoT Core doesn't give feedback
- better insight in why an application crashes
- hints for how to deal with a Visual Studio 2017 that simply stops responding instead of shows that the application crashes

Comment: You can try [Crash Reports of HockeyApp](https://hockeyapp.net/features/crashreports/#s).